# Dotnet ef core relations

Tags: .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core, relational-database

How can we have a one-to-many relationship when the primary key of all the models named Id?

Example:

```
public class Organization {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public List<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
}

public class Teacher {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long ??? { get; set; } // what do we call OrganizationId?
    public Organization Organization { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `public long OrganizationId { get; set; }`

Comment: @DavidG Even if the primary key in Organization model is not OrganizationId?

Comment: Perhaps you should go and run through some tutorials to understand how this all works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the variable with **???** should be called **OrganizationId**. I would create a separate class with the configuration for the model **Teacher**.

For example:

```
class TeacherConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Teacher>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<BoardCard> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(bc => bc.Id);
        builder.HasOne(bc => bc.Organization).WithMany(c => c.Teachers).HasForeignKey(bc => bc.OrganizationId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade).IsRequired();
    }
}
```